# An economy with no Pareto-efficient envy-free allocations

Tags: pareto-efficiency, fairness

In a [famous paper from 1974](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022053174900751), Hal Varian proved (in Theorem 2.3) that:

> In an economy with homogeneous divisible googs, if all agents have monotonic and [convex preferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_preferences), then there exists an allocation which is both Pareto-efficient and [envy-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envy-freeness).

He said (after Theorem 2.8) that, if preferences are not convex, then Pareto-efficient envy-free allocations might not exist. As an example, he brings the following economy: there are two agents with the same preferences:

$$u_1(x,y) = u_2(x,y) = \min(x,y)$$

and the total bundle is $(2,1)$.

I do not see how this is a negative example. If we give each agent a bundle of $(1,0.5)$, then the division is envy-free, since the value of every agent is exactly 0.5. It is also Pareto-efficient, since to increase the utility of one agent, it is necessary to give him some y from the other agent, but this hurts the utility of the other agent.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The preferences $$u_1(x,y) = u_2(x,y) = \min(x,y)$$ are convex. They are not strictly convex. I also don't see how a counterexample could be constructed using them.

Comment: Also, given these utility functions not any bundle is prefered to the $0$ bundle, so this seems quite strange.

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in the paper, and the function should be $\max$ instead of $\min$. Does it make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. Equitable allocations for that function provide 1 utility for each player, but that cannot be efficient as $(2,0)$, $(0,1)$ is feasible. And the utility function is not convex. I think you are right.

Comment: @denesp OK, good to know!